# rotate contents horizontally using JQuery

Tags: jquery, rotator

I wish to change the JQuery Rotator plugin below:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqRotator

The only change I needed is to navigate through Horizontally.. ie visitor will see two (or more) items firstly and then the new items will come from right side.

Is it possible ? or have any JQuery plugin to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0):

Actually quite easy to changed:

Roughly:
Whereever it says `height` (or where `height` is part of the name) change it to `width`. Where it says `scrollTop`, change it to `scrollLeft`..

Comment: Thank you for your post. I have changed but it doesn't work. But there is some change on the new page, as it seems rotating but not working exactly.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is the plugin you are looking for...

[rotate contents horizontally using JQuery](http://www.rgdesign.org/portfolio/2009/jquery.ease.slide.menu.v1/index.html)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Actually I am not looking for this plugin.

Comment: @gidson The package which has the same effect can be available at: http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/index.php#demo  Check on the "Auto Scroll" on right menu under "demos" section.